# Strange LaTeX PDF rendering in Firefox – letter "t" is bold

Tags: linux, pdf, firefox, latex, rendering

I have this problem with **Firefox 50.0** on **Fedora 23** and **GNOME 3.18.2**.

When I view a [PDF document](http://web.stanford.edu/~fringer/teaching/numerical_methods_02/handouts/lecture4.pdf) created in LaTeX, the letter "**t**" shows bold with default zoom:

[image]

---

When I zoom in, everything looks fine:

[image]

---

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I would expect problems like this to be solved readily, but I've been seeing this for a long time and I find it quite annoying.

Comment: Maybe antialiasing helps? That said I often see this kind of glitches

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also contains a list of other SE sites that you can look thru to find one appropriate for your questions (e.g. [superuser](http://superuser.com)].

Comment: I suggest asking this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/. Also a MWE is needed for this so other people can try to replicate.

Comment: I've just tried to display my own PDF from lualatex in FF (ubuntu), and it's not repro. Do you use latin modern fonts? (`\usepackage{lmodern}`)

Comment: @edison23 I added URL to the PDF in the question. I don't have the source.

Comment: @boofaz for me, the problem is not repro in my FF on any zoom level. http://screencloud.net/v/uH3FE . I use FF 53.0.3 (64-bit). However, if you don't have the source, there's nothing you can do except displaying the document in another viewer (try evince, for instance).

Comment: This question is not appropriate for tex.stackexchange.com as its a viewer problem.  Either zoom in/out, or use a different viewer program.